# Sourcing install setup.bash with cross compiled install

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros-jade, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS Jade on an Odroid XU4 (ARM) running Ubuntu 15.04. I have managed to successfully cross-compile a bare bones ROS Jade install, and moved the install_isolated folder to the Odroid. I source the setup.bash file and can start roscore, so far so good. However, when I cross-compile my own package (in a separate folder from the install) and move that devel folder to the board, then sourcing that setup.bash file removes the install_isolated/bin directory from the PATH and I can no longer start roscore.

When I cross compile my package on my computer I had sourced the install_isolated/setup.bash for the cross compiled install.

What steps do I need to take in order to not have my package's setup.bash file remove the install from PATH?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224941/sourcing-install-setup.bash-with-cross-compiled-install/) by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2016-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-25**:
May I suggest a title change? I'd suggest to include *at least* the fact that you're cross-compiling. Possibly also how you deploy to your target.

**Comment by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) on 2016-01-31**:
Thank you for the suggestion, let's hope it helps.

**Comment by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) on 2016-02-19**:
No respose in almost a month, I assume this means that either:

1. I am way off, or
2. It should work this way, at least in theory.
   But which one is it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is, no one else is using ROS like this. You're mostly on your own.

I *think* setup.sh has an `--extend` option that may let you source multiple setup.sh files in sequence, and extend your workspace instead of overwriting it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) on 2016-02-20**:
Thank you, using the --extend option when sourcing the second setup.bash works.
Am I alone in cross compiling my packages or in the way I move them to the target board?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-20**:
I don't know of anyone else who has gotten the cross-compilation process to work. If you have time to post instructions on how you're doing it, it would be greatly appreciated.